# How does updating embedded documents work in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

This is probably an obvious question, but I can't find a clear answer to it.

In MongoDB, suppose I embed document `food` into document `super_market`. When I make a change to the `food` document, will the embedded document in `super_market` automatically get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question denotes a structure like this:

example Super_market:

```
{ "super_market_name": "SuperMart",
  "address": "1 Main Street",
  "food": { "food_name":"apple" }
}
```

It sounds like you're asking about a food document that is separate from the super_market and linked to it.

If you embed the 'food' document as above, the embedded document is the one that you would be altering.  It doesn't exist in a separate location that you would modify.  If you update **super_market.food**, the embedded document is the one (and only) that will be affected.